# APEX 22.2 - Interactive Grid - "Average" Aggregation's "Overall Average" value - How to format to limit to 2 decimal places?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an "Interactive Grid" with a column with an "Average" aggregation with the "Show Overall Value" option checked.  The "Overall Average" values are showing with 20+ decimal places. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can limit the values to just 2 decimals?

[Apex IG Aggregation dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwZus.png)

[APEX IG "Overal Average" value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE7ch.png)

I've searched for a built-in (from APEX page designer or the rendered IG's "actions") means of specifying the max decimal places for an "average" aggregation, but so far I haven't found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- go to Page Designer
- navigate to "Days open" column
- scroll down to "Appearance" group of properties
- set **Format mask** property so that it displays two decimal places, e.g. `999G990D00`
- run the page

[image]

Comment: hi Littlefoot,
I appreciate the quick reply.   I had been hoping to render the IG detail line values as whole numbers and just the "Overall Average" with decimals (2).  However, it looks like what you're suggesting will be my simplest/best option. I.e., specify an "Appearance" > "Format Mask" for the IG's "DAYS_OPEN" column, which will propagate to the "Overall Average" aggregation.  I'm experimenting with the formats.  It's unfortunate that "FM9999D99” renders a whole number with a decimal.  (i.e., a value of "10" will render as "10.").  Thanks!

Comment: Try FM9990D00 instead.